# PHP MySQL JSON output formatting

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to output my database info with json formatting. The trick is the teamA/teamB is a value in the database.

Database is like this:

```
Team   timezome   time     fulldate
teamA   MST      8:30 PM    10-30-2014
teamA   CST      8:30 PM    10-30-2014
```

I need it formatting like this.

```
{
teamA: {
    timezone: "MST",
    time: "8:30 PM",
    fullDate: "10-30-2014"
},
teamB: {
    timezone: "CST",
    time: "8:30 PM",
    fullDate: "10-30-2014"
}
```

}

I can connect to everything and get the basic json output, I just can't wrap my head around formatting it like I want.

Thanks of any help.

Keith

Format i'm using now

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row_array['team'] = $row['team'];
    $row_array['date'] = $row['date'];
    $row_array['time'] = $row['time'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

and it's outputting

```
[
{
    team: "teamA",
    date: "11-29-14",
    time: "9:30"
},
{
    team: "teamB",
    date: "11-29-14",
    time: "9:30"
}
```

]

Comment: What is the format of the "basic JSON output"? How are you generating it? How does it vary from what you want?

Comment: I'm just using this `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        
        $row_array['team'] = $row['team'];
        $row_array['date'] = $row['date'];
        $row_array['time'] = $row['time'];
        
        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is just to iterate the result set, assign the value of the `Team` as an index of the return array, such as `$ret` for my example below. Assign the row to the index that we've just created, then unset the `Team` from the inner array that was built from the result of the `$row` array.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

$stmt = $mysqli->query('select * from my_table');

$ret = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
    $ret[$row['Team']] = $row;
    unset($ret[$row['Team']]['Team']);
endwhile;

echo json_encode($ret);
```

This should produce the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I had to use fetch_assoc(), fetch all gave me an error. The output is looking good except it doesn't loop if there are 2 of the same team names, which there will be.

Comment: @user3712837 Add a `GROUP BY Team` clause probably

Comment: @user3712837 Add `MYSQLI_ASSOC` as an argument to `fetch_all()` in order to ensure the results are returned `as an associative array`

Comment: When I use fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) I get this error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()

Comment: @user3712837 Then you're missing drivers, use `fetch_assoc` instead as you have. :) If memory serves...`fetch_assoc` actually has less permutations and minimizes it's impact on performance better than `fetch_all` anyway.

Comment: That's what I did, just didn't know if there was a reason to use either or. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "select * from tblname";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
While ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $arr [$res ['Team']] ['timezone'] = $res['timezone'];
  // do it for other two fields
}
```

Note: use of `mysql_` is deprecated.  This code is for only explaining and sample purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get a null on this one?    {
: {
time: null
}
}

Comment: @user3712837 Please don't use `mysql_` functions. They are `deprecated` and `slated for removal` in newer versions of PHP. Please consider using `Mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.